# Used FTP to transfer a large SAS dataset (~100 GB), how to verify that no data was left out?

Tags: ftp

I used FTP to transfer a ~100 GB SAS data set, I did not stay at my computer during the entire transfer process and when I got back the transfer appeared to be done, much quicker than I expected. I checked the file size from both origination and end, and the size is exactly the same (in bytes). Is there any chance of data being left out of the SAS data set or should everything have been transferred completely?

Comment: Hash every file (checksum) on the server and on the client, and compare the hashes.

Comment: If the transfer dropped or garbled some blocks then you should get errors when you try to read the data using SAS.  SAS datasets are binary format. So if it ends too soon then SAS will generate an error while reading it.

Comment: @Tom I am worried the transfer may have been interrupted since I was away when it took place. So I do not need to worry about the transferred data set missing or having blank data? What would happen if there was a error/interruption would be a corrupted data set that could not be opened/read anyways?